# How to override a specific value of log4j.properties?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using a jar that has `log4j.properties` included. One property of this jar maps to a static local resource with a path that does of course not exist on my system.

Problem: my custom log4j.properties is somehow not taken into account, even thought it is on the classpath.
What do I have to change so that the existing log4j from the jar remains valid, but only a specific value is overridden with my custom log4j?

`log4j.appender.InfoFileAppender.File=d:/logs/info.log`

Comment: Could you show the `log4j.properties` file content and point the problematic line?

Comment: properties from `log4j.appender` that the jar uses to create files in a location I don't have on my machine

Comment: You can get additional information about why your file is not taken into account by adding the `-Dlog4j.debug=true` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, Log4j should create the new file for you in most of the conditions. And if it cannot, read below.

By default, Log4j will load the first found "log4j.properties" in your class-path. 
So in your case,

a) if you want to load a custom log4j property file of the name "log4j.properties" with changes, make sure that it appears first in your class-path order.

b) You can load multiple custom log4j settings from different files using the PropertyConfigurator provided by Log4j. Even if you do this, i don't think you can override a particular property of an appender, because log4j wont load an appender again if it is already loaded.

c) The best approach would be to reassign a new file to the appender programmatically during the start up of your application.So you should have a piece of code which execute during startup which uses the Logger API's to gets the appender of the required logger and reset it.

Ok, in general,i say your use case is to validate the file existence before an appender is created,
you can add that validation check using a custom Configurator.

Log4j will use PropertyConfigurator to load your log4j.properties. You can define your own Configurator implementation which extends from Propertyconfigurator and write the code to make sure that appender file location is a valid one, and if not valid set it to a different one.
Make sure that you set the system property log4j.configuratorClass to tell Log4j that your Configurator should be loaded. Here i think you just need to override the parseAppender method from PropertyConfigurator.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but maybe useful for others who stumble upon it. I managed to overwrite a certain property this way:
http://aadityatiwari.com/2013/08/override-log4j-properties-at-runtime/

Of course, this won't help in your scenario, because you need to read the log4j.properties in memory first to override it.